# how to view pdf file in codeigniter using dompdf?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, dompdf

I can't figure out how can I view pdf file. it automatically download instead of viewing it in browser.

here is my code

```
public function index(){
    $data_user['users'] = $this->db->get('tbl_client')->result();
    $this->load->view('Dashboard/Print/user_list', $data_user);
    $html = $this->output->get_output();
    $this->load->library('pdf');
    $this->dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $this->dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    $this->dompdf->render();
    $this->dompdf->stream("mypdf.pdf");
}


SOLVED! With the answer below..
```

If still facing the issue. make sure you are not using any download manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
 $this->dompdf->stream("mypdf.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
 exit(0);
```

Comment: well the code is working. and the problem is I am using internet download manager. It downloads the pdf file. thanks!